# How could the gold and the passengers both be saved in the final sequence of the 1969 movie, Italian Job?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque

At the end of the Italian Job, the cast are left in *this* predicament;  the bus they are travelling on with a pile of gold has veered over the edge of a cliff and is balanced precariously with the gang members on one side and the gold on the exposed side.

Any attempt to leave the bus will condemn the gold to fall hundreds of feet down the Italian mountainside and, it is assumed, attract the police who are looking for it.

Video here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZCaSyid4m0

[image]
[image]
[image]

The gang leader played by Michael Caine, optimistically declares in the last line, from the floor of the tipping bus: "Hang on lads - I've got an idea!"

### **How could the team save themselves *and* the gold using real life physics?**

Edit:  It is obvious that the total tonnage of gold in the bus weighs more than the combined body weight of those in the back of the bus which renders the final scene implausible but for the sake of this question assume the masses are equal.

Comment: You also may want to look at the [tag:homework-and-exercises] tag info to see that we have a slightly different definition of homework, of which this question would be categorized as such.

Comment: I have read it and it is not homework.  I am rolling it back again.  I am not interested in how people find the answer or "guiding" me to the answer, I am interested in an actual answer.   Much like the Royal Chemistry Society were when they posed the same question to UK scientists.

Comment: Yes, your interest in the answer is pretty much what makes the [tag:homework-and-exercises] tag perfectly valid. My downvote is because the low-quality character of the question; the close vote is because it's a low-effort homework question.

Comment: Not according to the definition of homework question on the physics Meta and if the question is low quality then improve as per SE guidelines instead of downvoting out of pettiness.  Direct quote *" any question where it is preferable to guide the asker to the answer rather than giving it away outright."*  That is not what I am seeking here.  It's a genuine question, nothing homework about it.

Comment: @Venture2099 presumably then you can find additional information on the site of the RSC...

Comment: I don't think this question fits our definition of homework-like; it is, in my opinion, off-topic as "engineering" which we define as "using scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem" here. However I will refrain from casting a binding close vote and let the close reviewers decide about that.

Comment: A solution given in 2009. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-1126862/Italian-Job-DONE-fan-resolves-40-year-old-cliffhanger-classic-movie.html

Comment: Looks like he can touch it my stretching just a few inches more. That shouldn't make the difference. The hopefully, he can make some of it slide/move towards him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the people move their center of mass further back, perhaps by pressing against the back wall and/or hanging off the back of bus, the person who weighs the least could crawl over to the gold and pass it to the rest of the people until all of the mass of the gold is transferred and they can exit the bus with it.

It's essentially just playing with levers.

[image]

If you want to check out the math, [look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever#Virtual_work_and_the_law_of_the_lever).

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the back of the bus is what's hanging over the cliff. The gas tank is most likely at the back of the bus. Run the motor to empty the tank.

Answer (score 3):

If the leader is shown at the fulcrum point, then his mass doesn't matter. As a result, he can move to the front of the bus, and the lightest person in the gang can exit the bus and start carrying rocks into the bus. When one person's mass worth of rocks has been brought on board, the lightest person can then retrieve some gold. Storing the retrieved gold within the bus will allow more gold to be moved, and eventually several gang members can move to speed up the process.